# sharp region selection from blurry background in a single image using python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

In an image like the one attached below, I need to separate the foreground which is in fact the eyewear arm from the blurry glared background. 
[image: pls click to see the image]

For that I actually tried several different approaches. I tried codes of some recent research papers on sharp foreground extraction; but they do not give the desired results I am looking for. I also tried to use some blurry region extraction methods such as Gaussian and Fourier to discard the background; but they find some of the parts that to eyes are blurry as sharp regions. I also tried to use Hough transform to detect the straight lines, that although generally works better than other approaches, it still sometimes fails randomly and is difficult to generalize.

I have a background in computer vision but I am not particularly expert in image processing, hence my post here, in the search to hopefully get some clues from experts.

Comment: Do you have the image from the step before this in your processing chain? I think you went wrong there already...

Comment: This is the original image without any further processing yet. it is taken under dark-field lighting with a black&white camera.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is actually very difficult due to the fact that your in focus image is relatively similar to your background in terms of intensity, as well as the fact that your focused image contains two very different intensities (the white RayBan and the black glasses arm). Normally for segmenting objects out of an image they really need to be distinctly different from the background so you can do it by intensity alone. Basically all the simple options go out the window because the info you're looking to pull can't be pulled from this particular image using any sort of purely binary operations, so you need to do some grey scale operations.

As far as doing what you're looking for, you're probably looking for a combination of the blob tool, which will essentially segment the entire image into an array of objects based on connectivity. Then once you have all the blobs, you would go to each one and find the strength of the edges (generally, the larger the intensity difference the more in focus the object). Once you've done these two things, whichever blobs have a sufficiently high intensity you can mark as foreground objects and then segment them out and you're all done.

While this works in theory, for this particular image the blob tool may not segment the different objects sufficiently due to weak edges between the objects as well as their similar intensities. You could increase the connectivity/size of the border between objects by doing a few dilations, unfortunately that's a binary technique which adds a layer of difficulty to your problem.

TL;DR: Binarize the image, dilate it a few times to improve the connectivity of the edges, blob analysis to get a list of objects in the image by their connectivity, then go back to the original image, use the location info from the blob analysis to find the strength of the edges in the areas around the different blobs, then the strongest edges are going to be your most in focus portions which you can then segment out. Even after all this it might not work right still because this problem is genuinely difficult.

Comment: Thank Ryan, it is in fact a difficult problem. at this moment I am doing some blob analysis/processing and it feels already good that somebody else agrees this could lead towards a solution! I will keep you updated if it works. still I hope to receive other suggestions

Comment: It's definitely the way to go for this particular image... if you had a different image with better lighting there would be more options but for the task at hand with that image it sounds like you're on the right track

Answer (score 0):

Before segmentation, I would transform the original image into something measuring the "blurriness" per pixel. The least blurry part should then be your foreground to be segmented.

The tricky question is then, how to measure blurriness? You might want to have a look at 'cooccurrence matrix' metrics, 'histogram entropy' of a sliding window and some more (check literature) and combine them into a measure that works for your kind of input images.